# Building a Datetime Object for SQL database insert

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a small web form that requires the user to input (among other things), the scheduled backup time of whatever server they're adding to the system. The problem is, I'm struggling to find out the best way to take the user input and build a DateTime object (which is what the database requires).

I only really care about the Day of Week, Time of Day (12 or 24 hour clock).

I thought about just creating an empty DateTime object and then just adding my input values from the user, but you can only get, not set, the day of week, time of day, etc.

I've been looking at the Calender asp control, which would work for the day of the week selection, but I can't seem to find any support of time of day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to use a DateTime for a recurring event such as a backup.  A DateTime is useful for storing a particular date and time, but not a "template" for a recurring event.  Instead I'd use separate columns to store the day of week value (0-6) and time of date (minutes after midnight) for the event.

Comment: I suspect he's stuck with his datetime column, but +1 for right answer in the generic sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you going to use datepicker [here](http://sowkot.blogspot.com/2008/08/jquery-is-excellent-javascript-library.html) is one great sample for adding JQuery date picker using C#. That helped me including in my project evrn if I did know anything abaut JQuery and java sripts at all.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a immutable value type. You cannot set anything on it.

Assumed that you stick with DateTime on the DB and you don't want to use a DateTimePicker control.

You have to specify how the day of week and the time should be represented in the DateTime. You can start with DateTime.MinValue, the 1.1.0001, 12:00 at midnight, and add the day of week and the time. unfortunately, a regular DateTime field in a SqlServer 2005 is not able to store this date. So lets move it to the year 2000. The 1.1.2000 was a Saturday. You could calculate the DateTime like this:

```
int dayOfWeek; // 0 = mon, 6 = son
DateTime time;
DateTime scheduleTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, (dayOfWeek + 2) % 6 + 1) 
  + time.TimeOfDay;
```

**But honestly, I wouldn't do it.** It smells. I just answered your question. Listen to tvanfosson. He said everything that needs to be said.