# DateTime Object Representing Day of Week

Tags: c#, datetime, dayofweek

How can I convert a number between 1 and 7 into a DateTime object in C# which represents the day of the week? The numbers are coming from a XML file which I am parsing. I am retrieving each instance of a field containing a number between 1 and 7 which represents a day of the week between Sunday and Saturday.

Comment: Day of which week? When? Do you want something to take any date (which could be any point in any week), and return back the date that was say Monday of that week. Also in your head, do weeks start on Sunday or Monday?

Comment: See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764046/building-a-datetime-object-for-sql-database-insert/764172#764172

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume casting to a DayOfWeek object would give you a day of the week

```
DayOfWeek day = (DayOfWeek)myInt;
```

As far as a DateTime object goes, the object represents a specific day, not necessarily a random day of the week. You may try adding a # of days to a specific date if this is what you're trying to achieve.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a `DateTime`, you'd need a specific range of dates that you want the weekday to fall under (since a `DateTime` is a specific date and time, and a weekday isn't).

There is a `DayOfWeek` enumeration (whose values actually range from 0-6). If all you need is something to represent the day of the week, then you should be able to cast your int to a `DayOfWeek` like..

```
DayOfWeek myDay = (DayOfWeek)yourInt;
```

If you need an actual `DateTime`, you'll need a start date. You could then do...

```
DateTime myDate = startDate.AddDays(
    (int)startDate.DayOfWeek >= yourInt ? 
        (int)startDate.DayOfWeek - yourInt : 
        (int)startDate.DayOfWeek - yourInt + 7);
```

This will give you a DateTime for the next occuring instance of the day of the week you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` instance represents alway a complete date and cannot only represent a day of the week. If the actual date does not matter, take any monday (assuming 0 represents monday) and just add the number of the day.

```
Int32 dayOfWeek = 3;

// date represents a thursday since 2009/04/20 is a monday
DateTime date = new DateTime(2009, 04, 20).AddDays(dayOfWeek);
```

Else I agree with Adam Robinson's answer - if you just want to hold the day of a week, stick with the [DayOfWeek enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) (zero is sunday) instead of using an integer.

Answer (score 1):

DayOfWeek.Sunday is zero, so you could start with an arbitrary fixed date that you know to be Sunday, and add a value between 0 and 6:

```
public DateTime GetDayOfWeek(int dayOfWeek)
{
    if (dayOfWeek < 0 || dayOfWeek > 6) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);

    // 4 January 2009 was a Sunday
    return new DateTime(2009,1,4).AddDays(dayOfWeek);
}
```

I'm not sure why you would want this though.

If you only want it to get a localized version of the day of the week as in:

```
GetDayOfWeek(3).ToString("dddd"); // Gets name of day of week for current culture
```

an alternative would be to use DateTimeFormatInfo.DayNames or DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames for the culture you want.